# What is the energy expectation value of an imaginary time evolved quantum state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Suppose we are given an initial state $\Psi(0)$ and a Hamiltonian $H$. We can expand $\Psi(0)$ in terms eigenbasis of $H$, $\{ \phi_n \}$, as follows.
\begin{equation}
   \Psi(0) = \sum_n a_n  \phi_n .
\end{equation}
Using the formal solution for the time dependent Schrödinger equation we can express the quantum state at time $t$ by
\begin{equation}
  \Psi (t) = e^{-i H t} \psi(0) \qquad (\hbar=1). \label{eq1}
\end{equation}
Defining $\tau = it$, we can write
\begin{align}
  \Psi (\tau) &= e^{- H \tau} \psi(0) \\
   &= e^{- H \tau} \sum_n a_n  \phi_n \\
   &= \sum_n a_n e^{- E_n \tau} \phi_n ,
\label{eq3}
\end{align}
where $H_n \phi_n = E_n \phi_n$.

Now we seek to find the expectation value of energy of the state $\Psi{(\tau)}$.

To do this, we can first apply $H$ to $\Psi(t)$ to get
\begin{equation}
  H \Psi (\tau) = \sum_n a_n E_n e^{- E_n \tau} \phi_n
\label{eq4}
\end{equation}
Multiplying the above with $\Psi^*(\tau)$ and integrating, we get
\begin{equation}
\langle H \rangle =
   \sum_n |a_n|^2 E_n.
\end{equation}

This is the same expression one would get under real-time evolution.

My question is, a system undergoing imaginary time evolution is guaranteed to reach the ground state given there is some overlap between the ground state and the initial quantum state. The algorithm should produce quantum states whose energy decrease monotonically in time. My question is, how can one calculate the expectation value of an imaginary time evolved quantum state? My attempt at doing so, as outlined above, simply derives the time independent real time evolution results.

Comment: "This is the same expression one would get under real-time evolution." No, it's not, because $(e^{-E_n\tau})^* = e^{-E_n\tau}$, because that number is purely real. You actually get a factor of $e^{-2E_n\tau}$ in each term of the sum.

Comment: Perhaps a minor nitpick, but shouldn't it be $\Psi(\tau/i)$ since the argument is $t$?

Comment: Other minor nitpick. The symbol $\exp$ is usually reserved for the *name* of the exponential function with base $e$, whereas the symbol $e$ is used for the number. For this reason, you would write $\exp(-Ht)$ or $e^{-Ht}$ but not $\exp^{-Ht}$.

Comment: @march But isn't $E_n \tau = i E_n t$ purely imaginary?

Comment: The point behind imaginary time propagation is to *replace* $it$ with a *real* number $\tau$.  In this context, it's an *unphysical* replacement that makes the time-evolution *wrong* but allows you to numerically compute the ground state of the system. In other contexts (in quantum statistical mechanics, there's a funny relationship between imaginary time and *temperature* of condensed matter systems), it becomes physical, but here (if I understand the context), it just allows you to compute the ground state.

Comment: @march thank you so much. Indeed I am only trying to get to a ground state of a pure state. I have not formally studied imaginary time evolution, can you perhaps kindly guide me towards some pedagogical reference material I could use to understand this difference further?

Comment: I don't have a reference.  It's just something I learned along the way.  There's really not much *to* it though.  Each term in the sum has a decaying exponential factor $e^{-2E_n\tau/\hbar}$, and so the rate of decay is larger when $E_n$ is larger. Wait long enough, and the relative populations of the excited states are much lower than that of the ground state.